# how to Use jQuery to make a "get" Ajax call to the "/search" path on the server

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I need help debugging my project because it's not running correctly- in particular the JQuery/Ajax calls is where I think I have an error. The project essentially reads in a CSV file with artist, title, and a value of 0/1 on each line. Then when a user types into either of the two fields, artist or title, and clicks search, upon hitting search- the page should show a table of all the results from the csv file with the keyword the user typed in. Right now my issue is that when i enter say "abba" it should display all the titles and artists with the word abba in it. but it's not. nothing is showing up when I click search. but when i go to localhost/search i can see all the contents of the file being read in. So im not sure where to find my error.

I've tried changing the ajax calls a bit and I've tried doing a few calls a different way but nothing is working to get the values outputted to the screen. Here are all my files. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated as I'm new to JS.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Top 40 Search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Top 40</h1>
      <form>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Search Criteria</legend>
          <label for="Title">Title:</label>
          <input type="text" id="title" name="Title" placeholder="Enter Title">
          <label for="artist">Artist:</label>
          <input type="text" id="artist" name="artist" placeholder="Enter artist">
          <button type="button" id="search">Search</button>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Title</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
```

//css file:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #007bff;
  }
  
  form {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  
  fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  legend {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  
  label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #666;
  }
  
  input[type="text"] {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #333;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  
  button[type="button"] {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1rem;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  }
  
  button[type="button"]:hover {
    background-color: #0062cc;
  }
  
  table {
    margin: 20px auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  
  th, td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  
  th {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
  }
  
  tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }
  
  tbody tr.gold:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: gold;
  }
  
  tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
  }
```

//app.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
//needed fs to read in file: 
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();

const publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "public");
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.use("/jquery", express.static(__dirname + "/node_modules/jquery/dist/"));

//create a class Song with a constructor that creates 
//three fields: title, artist, and numone.
class Song {
  constructor(title, artist, numone) {
    this.artist = artist;
    this.title = title;
    this.numone = numone;
  }
}
//read in csv file: 
const fileContent = fs.readFileSync('top40.csv', 'utf-8');
const lines = fileContent.split("\r\n");

//using map method: 
const songs = lines.map(line => {
  const fields = line.split(","); 
  const artist = fields[1].replace(/^'|'$/g, "");
  const title = fields[2].replace(/^'|'$/g, "");
  const numone = fields[3] === "1";
  return new Song(artist, title, numone);
});

//test printing to console: 
// songs.forEach(song => {
//   console.log(`${song.title} by ${song.artist}${song.numone ? " (No. 1)" : ""}`);
// });

app.get('/search', function(req, res) {
  var title = req.query.title ? req.query.title.toLowerCase() : '';
  var artist = req.query.artist ? req.query.artist.toLowerCase() : '';

  var filteredSongs = songs.filter(function(song) {
    var songArtist = song.artist.toLowerCase();
    var songTitle = song.title.toLowerCase();
    
    return (artist === '' || songArtist.includes(artist)) && (title === '' || songTitle.includes(title));
           
  });

  res.send(JSON.stringify(filteredSongs));
});


app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
  res.end("Invalid Request.");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

//script.js file:

```
//ajax calls: 

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Bind click event to Search button
    $('#search').click(function() {
      // Retrieve title and artist keywords
      var title = $('#title').val();
      var artist = $('#artist').val();
      //now utilize keywords: 
       // Make GET Ajax call to server
       $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/search",
        data: {
          artist: artist,
          title: title 
        },
        processData: true,
        success: function(response) {
          // Empty out previous results
          $('#table').empty();
          
          // Iterate through search results and create table rows
          response.forEach(function(song) {
            var row = $('<tr>');
            row.append($('<td>').text(song.artist));
            row.append($('<td>').text(song.title));
            if (song.numone) {
              row.addClass('numone');
            }
            $('#table').append(row);
          });
        },
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Check your jquery selectors.  #search and #table are looking for dom elements that have id=search and id=table specifically.   your table element has no id set.  So when ajax call comes back, it cant find an element into which to add children

Comment: omg i didnt realize that ty, but it still wont print out items in the table. so the same issue^

Comment: in your  ajax success callback function... do a console.log(typeof response) to see what you are getting back.  assuming your api call is working, the response variable may not be of type array... which means that you  cant use .forEach() on it...  you may have to manually json.parse(response) first...